# java CallableStatement failed, while calling function of postgreSQL enterprise edition

Tags: java, postgresql, enterprisedb

**Case History:**

I have upgraded postgreSQL normal to Enterprise edition

Old version:
PostgreSQL 9.5.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55), 64-bit

New Version:
 EnterpriseDB 9.5.0.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55), 64-bit

Taken complete dump from old and imported in new version.

Problem statement:

While We are accessing postgre function from new version (Enterprise) (by making connection from java 1.8). Getting below error although there is no problem with establish connection with postgreSQL enterprise.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A CallableStatement was executed with an invalid number of parameters
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgCallableStatement.executeWithFlags(PgCallableStatement.java:106)
```

This error comes for all 144 functions. Is there any change in java callableStatement and prepared statement while using enterprise PostgreSQL ? Although same procedures are working while establish connection with old version of PostgreSQL.

Please suggest

BR// Mohit M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced same problem.

I think you are using postgresql-9.4.1211.jre6.jar. Problem will be resolved by replacing the jar to postgresql-9.4.1209.jre6.jar.

Comment: Thanks Rahul and Ashish Yadav for the solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

For me instead of  `CallableStatement`, `PreparedStatement` worked.
I was using following code using `CallableStatement` before

```
CallableStatement objCallableStatement = null;
objCallableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call alad_balad(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

objCallableStatement.setLong(1, 431);
objCallableStatement.setString(2, "12434");
objCallableStatement.setString(3, "1234");
objCallableStatement.setString(4, "en");
objCallableStatement.setString(5, null); 
objCallableStatement.setString(6, null);
objCallableStatement.setShort(7, Short.parseShort("0"));
objCallableStatement.setString(8, null);
objCallableStatement.setLong(9, 1);
objCallableStatement.setString(10, "1234");
objCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(11, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
objCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(12, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
objCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(13, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
objCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(14, java.sql.Types.BIGINT);
objCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(15, java.sql.Types.OTHER);
objCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(16, java.sql.Types.OTHER);
objCallableStatement.execute();
```

Now for enterprise version I am using the following code

```
PreparedStatement objPreparedStatement = null;
try{
objConnection = objConnectionDataSource.getConnection();
objPreparedStatement = objConnection.prepareCall("{call alad_balad(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

objPreparedStatement.setLong(1, 431);
objPreparedStatement.setString(2, "12434");
objPreparedStatement.setString(3, "1234");
objPreparedStatement.setString(4, "en");
objPreparedStatement.setString(5, null); 
objPreparedStatement.setString(6, null);
objPreparedStatement.setShort(7, Short.parseShort("0"));
objPreparedStatement.setString(8, null);
objPreparedStatement.setLong(9, 1);
objPreparedStatement.setString(10, "1234");

objPreparedStatement.execute();
   ResultSet res = objPreparedStatement.getResultSet();
   String in = null;
   while ( res.next() ){
     in = res.getString(1);
     System.out.println(in);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks , Changed preparedStatement and it work for me